# Beginner Prolog question - comparison always returns false

Tags: prolog

I have a very simple Prolog function but Prolog always returns `false` from the comparison and I can't work out why.  I want to take `N` letters of the alphabet and put them in a list.  So if I call it with `N=6`, I want `[A,B,C,D,E,F]`.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
create([],_,_,[]).
create([X|XS],Length,Acc,[X|NewList]) :-
    Acc<Length, create(XS,Length,Acc+1,NewList).
```

I get this when I run it using SWIPL:

```
?- create([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z],6,0,Nodes).
false.
```

But if I take out the `Acc<Length` it creates a list of 26 letters:

```
?- create([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z],6,0,Nodes).
NewList = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I|...].
```

Comment: Have you looked at the tracer? it is funny how you use "Acc+1", but never mind.

Comment: Second comment: you get Variables, not letters.

Comment: Third comment: you need to specify what should happen if Length is equal to Acc, sorry evaluates to the same value as Acc.

Comment: Hi tiffi, I'm not sure what's wrong with Acc+1 - why is it funny?  Yes, I specifically want variables to use in the next function.  If I'm checking that Acc is less than Length it will never be equal to Length so why would I need to check that?  I'm still stuck on why the evaluation using less than doesn't work.

Comment: I already told you, why (my 3rd remark) In addition: please look at the tracer. It is started with `?-trace.` and ended with `?-notrace.`

Comment: I see. I get it now. It almost works but gives me a weird number at the end: NewList = = [A, B, C, D, E, F|_25614].  Do you know what might cause that?

Comment: That the clause you have added is not yet what you were looking for. Edit your question and let us see. (Guess you should think about empty lists)

Comment: create([],_,_,[]).
create([Head|Tail],Length,Acc,[Head|NewList]):-
    Acc<Length, create(Tail,Length,Acc+1,NewList),!.
create([Head|Tail],Length,Acc,[Head|NewList]):-
    Acc=:=Length.

Comment: NewList is _25614 from your comment above.

Comment: Yes, where does that _25614 come from?  The result I'm after is [A,B,C,D,E,F] (if N=6) or [A,B,C] if N=3 etc.  I can't work out why it's putting _25614 on the end.

Comment: Prolog renames variables. As I said, _25614 is Prolog's name for NewList.

Comment: Also, if Length =:= Acc, you don't want to add anything any more, right? so replace `[Head|NewList]` by `[]`.

Comment: Great, thanks for your time, it's great that you can help beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that summarizes our discussion in the comments, but uses beautiful pattern matching:

```
create(_,Length,Length,[]).
create([Head|Tail],Length,Acc,[Head|NewList]):- 
    Acc<Length, 
    Acc1 is Acc + 1,
    create(Tail,Length,Acc1,NewList).
```

As a bonus, here is another solution:

```
create(List, Length, Solution):-
    length(Solution, Length),
    append(Solution, _, List).
```

---

**Edit:**
Rethinking it, I am not so sure any more that this is what you want, since probably with your first clause, you want to specify what is supposed to happen when List has less members than Length and that is to return the full list.

Ok, then correct answers would be:

```
create([],_,_,[]).
create(_,Length,Length,[]).
create([Head|Tail],Length,Acc,[Head|NewList]):- 
    Acc<Length, 
    Acc1 is Acc + 1,
    create(Tail,Length,Acc1,NewList).
```

and

```
create(List, Length, Solution):-
    length(Solution, Length),
    append(Solution, _, List), 
    !.
create(List, _, List).
```